# copy packet data to another packet using SFML in c++

Tags: c++, sfml

Can anybody tell me how to copy SFML the data of a `sf::Packet` instance (e.g. `packet1`) to another instance (e.g. `packet2`)?

I know how to get a packet data but the problem is that I cannot set it as packet2's data. This is what I mean:

```
sf::Packet packet;                      // a compressing variable
sf::Packet packet2;                     // a compressing variable2

const void* get1 = packet.getData();    // get the data of above packet variable
packet2 << get1;                        // did not worked
```

The problem is that I cannot bring `packet1`'s data to `packet2`.
I've tried this so far which did not work!

All replies are appreciated, and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used SFML, but from reading the [SFML documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1Packet.php), I would expect:

```
const void* get1 = packet.getData();
size_t len = packet.getDataSize();
packet2.append(get1, len);
```

Comment: guess that doesn't works after doing it the way you said like packet2.append(get1, len); so when i try like printf("%s\n\n\n", get1); i show the exact data but when i try printf("%s\n\n\n\n", packet2.getData()); i show totally different thing and very low.

Comment: @Wajid Bummer. Worth a try. What was the length returned by `packet.getDataSize()`?

Comment: 8821 was the length returned by packet.getDataSize();

Comment: So nothing ridiculous  like getDataSize coming back with zero. How about the result of `packet2.getDataSize()` after the append call? Be interesting to see how many bytes were written or if there was already something incompatible inside packet2.

Comment: that is much higher than the packet datasize it actually was random but started with the 25021 or something

Comment: @Wajid . Nuts. Try getting packet2's datasize before appending anything to it. If the result isn't zero, it smells like the packet doesn't get initialed to empty when created. In that case, see what happens with `packet2.clear()` before the append call.

Comment: @Wajid an afterthought. if all you have in packet is a string, you can read that out with `std::string str; packet >>str;` and then `packet2 << str;` should write the string into packet2.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to copy `packet1` into `packet2` as you would do for any "*value-type*" object.

Here is an example:

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    sf::Packet p1;
    p1 << "A string" << 42;

    sf::Packet p2 = p1;

    std::string str;
    int i;

    p1 >> str >> i;
    std::cout << "1) str: " << str << ", i: " << i << std::endl;

    p2 >> str >> i;
    std::cout << "2) str: " << str << ", i: " << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```